# web based subversion viewer

Tags: svn, trac

Is there a tool that allows me to point to a subversion repository to browse the contents of the repository. I am thinking something similar to what trac provides with SCM. I describe some of the features here for those not familiar with trac's source integration:

- access it from a browser - it must be a webapp
- ability to view any version of a file. Preferably this feature can be invoked using a url. This means one can link to a specific version of a file.
- display on a single page all the modified files in a changeset (gravy: show the diffs of the modified files)
- ability to display (in a color coded way) the diff between two versions of a file with the ability to invoke it using a url.
- a time line of changes to the repository with modified files for each changeset.
- It would be great if it's open source but doesn't have to be.

What other features should a whizzbang web based repository viewer have?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with trac. we don't want to use the bug tracking features of trac so it would be nice to have a stand along repository viewer.

Comment: VisualSVN Server's web interface has the features you specify in the question: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/3.2/#commit-view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/) with [Cruise Control .Net integration](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Subversion+Source+Control+Block#Linking%20modifications%20to%20WebSVN), so every build email shows the files modified and click on them shows a diff

I like trac much better but can't get my company to switch

Comment: it's great to know that there is cruise control integration. thanks.

Comment: Interesting- didn't know you could do, I might have to check it out.

Answer (score 8):

We use [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/). It has all of the features mentioned above. The reason we don't use trac is because we use FogBugz as our issue tracker, and since websvn was purely a repository browser, it fit well with FogBugz.

Comment: You got there 2 seconds before me! Nice

Comment: thanks. we also use something else for issue tracking so I am hesitant in using trac

Answer (score 3):

Sventon is an excellent repository browser. I've written earlier about what I like about Sventon [here](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/03/sventon-a-nice-subversion-repository-browser.html).

I think Sventon meets your requirements (my understanding from your question), and some other nice stuff:

- Web application and so WAR installation is a breeze.
- Easy configuration.
- Support for multiple repositories.
- Files/directories can be downloaded as compressed archives (zip).
- Diff is good, three modes — inline, side-by-side and unified diff.
- If you are using Hudson for build management Sventon is supported.
- If you are using Jira and using Subversion plugin, relatively easy configuration.

Comment: Please include a link.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to slim down Trac, components can be enabled and disabled via *trac.ini*.  Take a look at the [components](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#components-section) section of the TracIni documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here at my company we use [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [WebSvn](http://websvn.tigris.org/). But I haven't tried much else.