# A viewer for subversion

Tags: c#, svn

I'm looking for a viewer to be used over a subversion repository. I saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195322/web-based-subversion-viewer) but I don't want a web based viewer, but rather one I can combine into software.
The purpose of this viewer is to enable the SW's users to save versions of the code they write in it and to search for content written by others.
Since our SW is written in C#, I'd prefer something with C# API.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Viewing different versions of files is also important.

Comment: it sounds like you are writing your own viewer that will interact with a subversion repository. If that's the case, then look at Lucene.net (http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for enabling code searching over the repository. Obviously, there's quite a bit of development work to get the code exported from Subversion and stored in Lucene! Our company is working on a product to do just this at the moment, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: I don't. It's a near-future project and I'm trying to find suitable tools to save us developing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include SVN-based functionality into your software, you might want to use

- [sharpsvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

It's licensed under the Apache License, so you can use it in commercial projects (with some conditions, read the license for details). I have no personal experience with it, so I don't know if it already includes a viewer component or just the bare SVN client code. In any case, the front page lists a lot of open-source projects built upon sharpsvn, maybe one of those would be a suitable candidate for inclusion in your software (if the license fits your needs).

Comment: I've been planning to use it as an SVN wrapper, but I also want a viewer to be used by my customers. I suppose I'll write it myself. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to integrate SVN with your application, check out [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/). That's the library used by some of the major SVN plugins around today (AnkhSVN, etc).

If you specifically want to view different versions of files, check out the [SvnClient class](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/AllMembers_T_SharpSvn_SvnClient.htm) in the [SharpSVN docs](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/). Unfortunately the docs are quite incomplete, but their naming conventions look to be enough to help you find what you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio, [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is a great plug-in - recommended. This simplifies the check-in process for Visual Studio considerably.

For searching for work done by others the [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) client is a good complement as it's a plug-in for Windows Explorer. It includes a Repository Browser that has excellent search (and merge) capabilities.

Comment: Neither Tortoise nor Ankh have an API that the OP can use from C#, do they?

Answer (score 0):

We have been using TortoiseSVN which is an easy-to-use SCM / source control software for Microsoft Windows. It is implemented as a Windows shell extension, which makes it integrate seamlessly into the Windows explorer. Since it's not an integration for a specific IDE you can use it with whatever development tools you like.